# Ffmpeg audio tracks are missing after trimming using filter_complex

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trimming a video file having multiple audio tracks using filter complex trim command,

```
/usr/bin/ffmpeg -y -i "Sequence1.mxf" -filter_complex "[0:v]trim=start=4.769:end=32.401 setpts = PTS-STARTPTS [V0];[0:a]atrim=start=4.769:end=32.401 asetpts = PTS-STARTPTS [A0]" -map [V0] -map [A0] "otput.mp4"
```

But the output will only have one audio track, as I believe this is because ffmpeg will choose one audio track from the input. I am not able to find out how to preserve all the tracks and channels in the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The atrim filter is only operating upon a single stream, and that's the only stream mapped.

For this use case, the following command is simpler,

```
/usr/bin/ffmpeg -y -i "Sequence1.mxf" -ss 4.769 -to 32.401 -map 0 "output.mp4"
```

Comment: The above works for mxf to mp4, but when i specify output as .mxf it gives error "-d10_channelcount requires MXF D-10 and will be ignored", failed to find absolute offset of 6778F48 in BodySID 1 - partial file? .

Comment: I used filtercomplex trim as I want to merge 2 trimmed video files of different source. How can we achieve this by preserving audio streams

Comment: For D10, you have to add `-f mxf_d10` as an output option.